# is it necessary to close a view controller before moving to next view controller

Tags: ios, iphone

I am an android developer trying to make an iOS app. i need to know how iOS deals with 2 things.

1. My app has a login screen and home screen. in the android app i have to finish the login screen before moving to the home-screen or the user can go back to login screen when back is pressed. should i do something to finish my login view controller before moving to home view controller?
2. If i don't have to finish my login screen. when log out is clicked from the home screen should i pop my home view controller to go to my login. or create a new login?

Comment: use UINavigationControloler, pushViewController shows the new view controller and popviewController  removes the new view controller and shows the login view again. read some apple docs on UIViewControllers,UINavigationControllers

Comment: You need to take a Look at these Docs, **ARC** && **UINAvigationController**

Comment: @santhu i know that. the question is do you generally pop all the views above the login when logout is pressed or just push a new login to the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to remove login screen after login in iOS. If you use `pushViewController` to navigate to home screen, iOS creates a stack of view controller. So that user can go back to previous screen with default back button. You can hide the default back button and add your own button for `Logout` at you home screen like this.

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Add your own button

```
UIBarButtonItem *logoutButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:@"Logout"                                            
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(logoutUser)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = logoutButton;
logoutButton = nil;
```

In `logoutUser` method, just do all you session destroy or cleanup, and call following method to go back to your login screen.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```